# Broken not fixable unity

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz

I was playing minecraft and I used the kill -15 -1 command and it broke my unity and I can't get it to work again even with the CompizConfig methods. If I am duplicating topics then post a link to another method and I will try it.

Thanks, Kraken

PS: I am greeted on login by my blank wallpaper and mouse nothing else works and I can only access the full screen terminal.

Comment: Have you tried http://askubuntu.com/q/17381/178596 ?

Comment: Yes that was the first one I tried

Comment: Have you tried all options / suggestion there ? I had the exact issue and this suggestion  fixed it instantly .. http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/290376#290376

Comment: Ill try when i get a chance (4 more days).